# Will there be any issue with re-entry to US with H1B visa set to expire in 4 months?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, h1b-visas

I am planning to take a 1 week trip outside the US in April 2018. My H1B visa expires first week of September 2018. I just want to know if there will be any issue at port of entry in the US with 4 months left on my H1B visa. Thanks.